# Binding a variable to an unbound variable

Tags: plotting, variable-definitions, variable

I'm trying to do something like the following: (minimal example, `f2` unbound)

```
case = 2;
f = Switch[case, 1, f1, 2, f2]
Plot[{f2^2}, {f, 0, 10}]
```

but the plot comes out blank. The second line outputs `f2` so it does recognize that f=f2. Any recommendations?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Something along the lines of 

`f1 = Sin[x];
f2 = x^2;

case = 2;
f = Switch[case, 1, f1, 2, f2];
Plot[{f^2}, {x, 0, 10}]`? If so, you should check your variables and assignments. `f` is (presumably) a function, but you'd want `Plot` to iterate over a variable in that function (`x` in my example), not over `f`.

Comment: `Plot` has the `HoldAll` attribute, so the second argument will not be evaluated (or any of the arguments for that matter). Try `Plot[{f2^2}, Evaluate@{f, 0, 10}]`.

Comment: @sebhofer your `Evaluate@` trick worked perfectly and is simple, thanks!